# I want a way to reduce java GUI code

Tags: java

suppose I want to design Java GUI frame with 30 radio box on it . Are there any way to add them without write many lines of code may about 60 line ?

Comment: You can use a for loop

Comment: Yes. You can write everything in one line.

Comment: Yes you can do it in a few lines. It depends on what you want in each line, though. Why not explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: if I have code below I cann't use for loops :(
JRadioButton rectangular = new JRadioButton("R");
JRadioButton polar = new JRadioButton("P");
JRadioButton spherical = new JRadioButton("S"); 
JRadioButton cylindrical = new JRadioButton("C");

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21508682/edit) your question and add more details there, not in comments.

Comment: Of course you can. Put your buttons in an array or list, and iterate.

Comment: do all options start with a different letter?

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=1; i <30; i++){
//radio check box adding code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare all radio button names in an array and do the iteration like following,

String[5] radioString = {"P","Q","R","S","T"};   //declare as much as you want
for(String radioName : radioString){
      JRadioButton rectangular = new JRadioButton(radioName);
}
```